# Core Location crashes in iOS extension

Tags: ios, core-location, crashlytics, ios-extensions

I'm getting many crash reports from my iOS today extension in Crashlytics which I can't make any sense of. The extension retrieves the user's current location and saves it inside the app. The crashes look like this:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x174132fc0.events
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000f2cdbeb8
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194d7fbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001834823f8 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 236
2  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183d1c09c (null) + 54344
3  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183d1adf0 (null) + 49564
4  libxpc.dylib                   0x00000001955c4ccc _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
5  libxpc.dylib                   0x00000001955c8a18 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 124
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x00000001955c8970 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 96
```

Here is another one:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1743221c0.events
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186678640 CFBasicHashGetBucket + 28
1  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866785c4 CFBasicHashApply + 100
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866785c4 CFBasicHashApply + 100
3  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866823d8 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 204
4  CoreLocation                   0x0000000186f1c09c (null) + 54344
5  CoreLocation                   0x0000000186f1adf0 (null) + 49564
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x0000000198814ccc _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x0000000198818a18 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 124
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x0000000198818970 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 96
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x00000001988188e4 notify_server + 100
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x0000000198812a98 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1848
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019860da28 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198611140 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 492
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001986182d4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2008
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198610668 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 136
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001986182d4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2008
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198610a5c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001986182d4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2008
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198610a5c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019861a318 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019861bc4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001987ed22c _pthread_wqthread + 816
```

As you can see none of my own classes is visible in the stack trace.

How can I debug this? Do these crashes appear to the user?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you added core location framework?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh i cannot have this error. I added this fw, will it fix the error ?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh I've imported Core Location in my code and turned "Link Frameworks Automatically" on. Do I additionally have to link the framework in my project settings?

Comment: Btw, adding fw did not fix the error. Fyi.

Comment: I'm have the same error. Have you solved this?